# NSWindow in front of NSMenu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nswindow, nsmenu

Is it possible to show an `NSWindow` in front of a `NSMenu`, so that it is not hidden behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that by "menu" you mean the main menu bar at the top of the screen? In that case,

`[window setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1];`

should do the trick for you.

Comment: That does not seem to work for me even though I understand why it should. And by "menu" I mean an `NSMenu` popup from an `NSStatusItem`.

Comment: Yeah, just checked. That line is from one of our projects where we create a full-screen window that just needs to sit above main menu bar and dock; probably not relevant for your case anyways, then.

Comment: @Joshua: In that case, I think you'll want `NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel` instead of `NSMainMenuWindowLevel`.

Comment: `[window setLevel:NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel+1];` Doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: It works now, I had to subclass NSWindow and put it in there which was odd.